# Removing comments number markers in a WordPress template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am building a theme based on Underscore's startup theme. I have applied custom styles to their `comments.php` template, and stumbled on a comment number marker. How do I remove it from the template?

I can't even inspect those numbers. Take a look at the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is most likely a list style, a css style. Do you have a link or something?

Comment: Omg, you have a right. I didn't think about it. I have <ol> tag and just set list-style:none; and it disappears. Thank you.

Comment: @GordanaJekic, you should post an answer then.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and used the following CSS to hide the numbers -

```
.comment-list{ list-style-type:none; }
```